# Shopware 6.5: Get a SalesChannelProductEntity from Order Line Items?

Tags: shopware6

I work with the `SalesChannelRepositoryIterator` and `SalesChannelProductRepository` when fetching Products.

Now I want to fetch Orders and need to iterate through them. I use the `RepositoryIterator` with the `OrderRepository` to get the Orders from the Database. When looping through the OrderItems I do `$product = $lineItem->getProduct();` But then I get the `ProductEntity` and not the `SalesChannelProductEntity` which I need.

How can I get the `SalesChannelProductEntity` from the OrderItems? Or is there any way to migrate from a `ProductEntity` to a `SalesChannelProductEntity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solution would be to simply fetch the product while iterating using `sales_channel.product.repository`. Otherwise you'd have to implement your own `SalesChannelDefinitionInterface` for the `order` entity.

You'll have to assemble a `SalesChannelContext` to fetch the sales channel variant of the product entity. You can use the `OrderConverted` service to do so.

```php
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addAssociations([
    'lineItems',
    'transactions',
]);

$iterator = new RepositoryIterator(
    $this->orderRepository,
    $context,
    $criteria
);

foreach ($iterator->fetch()->getEntities() as $order) {
    $salesChannelContext = $this->container->get(OrderConverter::class)
        ->assembleSalesChannelContext($order, $context);

    foreach ($order->getLineItems() as $lineItem) {
        $product = $this->container->get('sales_channel.product.repository')->search(
            new Criteria([$lineItem->getProductId()]),
            $salesChannelContext
        )->first();

        var_dump($product instanceof SalesChannelProductEntity);
    }
}
```